How should I use space so it works on my code in row. I'm using flutter between
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TrackerWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const TrackerWidget({
    super.key,
    required this.bgIcon,
    required this.title,
    required this.time,
    required this.size,
    this.isNotificationEnabled = false,
    this.isDone = false,
    required this.timeEnum,
  });

  final String bgIcon;
  final String title;
  final String time;
  final double size;
  final bool isNotificationEnabled;
  final bool isDone;
  final String timeEnum;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: size,
      height: size,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage(bgIcon),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(7),
      child: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: [
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 17,
                width: double.infinity,
                color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.2),
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                constraints: BoxConstraints(),
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    NotificationWidget(
                      isNotificationEnabled: isNotificationEnabled,
                      time: timeEnum,
                    ),
                    const Spacer(),
                    NotificationWidget(
                      isNotificationEnabled: isNotificationEnabled,
                      time: timeEnum,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NotificationWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const NotificationWidget({
    super.key,
    required this.isNotificationEnabled,
    required this.time,
  });

  final bool isNotificationEnabled;
  final String time;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
      // constraints: const BoxConstraints(),
      icon: Container(
        width: 16,
        height: 16,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(120),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


I've written above code to achieve below image
What I've achieved
As you can see I'm adding spacer between notification widget, but they're not going to edge of widgets. Red container I've added just to see where are constraints. What's wrong? Please help
I've expected that two circles will be at the edges of widget.
I've been on latest version of flutter. Thought maybe there's problem and already downgraded to 3.22 version

Try to give mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween to Row and remove spacer.

Practice posting your code instead of image so others can easily check with the code.

@DroidFlutter I've already tried spacesBetween. It's also not working

Please read Why should I not upload image of code/data/errors?

@TologonKudaiberdi, source code should be posted as formatted text with your question. Text is easier to inspect and can be copied/pasted to write an answer. To improve the quality of your question, you should amend it by pressing the edit button and pasting the code.  This is also what DroidFlutter suggested.

you can view my code from https://codeshare.io/J7ylDq

I've edited my post. Now you can copy or view easily

@TologonKudaiberdi added code for this. Please check

The problem is with the IconButton I don't know exactly why it's not working try using GestureDetector
    class NotificationWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const NotificationWidget({
    super.key,
    required this.isNotificationEnabled,
    required this.time,
  });

  final bool isNotificationEnabled;
  final String time;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Container(
        width: 16,
        height: 16,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(120),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Try to replace your NotificationWidget with given widget. Hope it helps...
class NotificationWidget extends StatelessWidget {
      const NotificationWidget({
        super.key,
        required this.isNotificationEnabled,
        required this.time,
      });

  final bool isNotificationEnabled;
  final String time;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    constraints: BoxConstraints(),
      onPressed: () {},
      icon: Container(
        width: 16,
        height: 16,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(120),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


-Change
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween: Added to align the NotificationWidget at both ends. - check Image

Removed Spacer(): Removed the Spacer() widget and replaced its functionality with MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween.

Already tried. Not working
